# Alternative to read.transaction() in r?

Tags: r, apriori

I have the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)
data <- fread('offline.csv')
library(plyr)
transactionData <- ddply(data,c("CUSTOMER_NO"),
                         function(data)paste(data$Category,
                                            collapse = ","))
transactionData$CUSTOMER_NO <- NULL
colnames(transactionData) <- c("items")

write.csv(transactionData,"market_basket_transactions.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
tr <- read.transactions('market_basket_transactions.csv', format = 'basket', sep=',')
```

Total transaction are round 60Million. Is there a faster way around in reading the read.transaction().

Comment: Try saving the transaction data as rds instead of csv.

Comment: To be able to convert the data directly into transactions, you need a list.  There are examples in the manual page (? transactions).